# Cross compiling Lua and libs for embedded ARM device

Tags: lua, embedded, cross-platform

Whats the best procedure to cross compile lua and libs (luasockets, orbit, etc) for an embedded arm device.

Im able to succesfully cross compile lua interpreter, but from there im a little bit lost.

Comment: Is the question here "How do I cross-compile lua?" or is it "How do I cross-compile at all?" Have you tried anything? Have you cross-compiled anything else?

Comment: i cross compiled lua interpreter but then i need to cross-compile luasocket, which has c code and lua code, so i think i should have a lua interpreter in the host machine also.  Im looking for an easy way to cross compile a basic lua enviroment like https://github.com/keplerproject/kepler

Comment: You don't need to cross-compile lua code. If that's what you were thinking about. Cross-compiling the C part should be enough. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

I started using this repo as a base some years ago: https://github.com/johnhw/luajitpi

The whole process depends on what OS your device is running and how POSIX-ish it is. If your system provides a BSD-like-socket API the process should be trivial.

The same applies for pthreads and other APIs your OS should provide. We're running eCos for example, which has a small POSIX layer so the porting of libs like luasocket was easy.